# using session.use_cookies with sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

in functions.php I'm using

```
ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
ini_set("session.auto_start",1);
```

as i cant use cookies on my webpage. But it causes me some problems. I have implemented captcha on my webpage.

Than I have index.php, where sessions works fine. Bu in that source code I have captcha:

```
<div class="captcha left4">
    <img src="captcha.php" alt="" width="220" height="49" />
</div>
```

In captcha.php I have included: include ('inc/functions.php'); 
and 
    $code = 'some_captcha_string';
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = $code;

but when in index.php I show print_r($_SESSION); there is empty $_SESSION['captcha']. And $_SESSIONS filled in directly in index.php are filled after print.

when I comment out that 4 lines at begining of index.php, it is working perfectly. But the problem is, that i want to avoid cookies.

where could be problem?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using cookie for session identification?  using URL based session ID has big security issues, as the URL can be shared and anyone can access the session..  I think you need to address the 'problems' that using cookies are giving you rather than implement this method.

Comment: that webpage is used as iframe at my client page. On my webpage is created login to my database. Loged user is stored in session. And there problems occours. I dont know why but its stored somehow in cookies. Problem with showed url isnt problem, as its like iframe, and even if somebody open it in new frame, there is no security data which could be abused. so i found solution that its pssible to do it with that 4 lines. which is working good, except of storing captcha in session

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: version 5.5.8 build date Jan 8 2014